# How to replace a specific substring, keep the following word, and add a new substring behind using SQL-update?

Tags: replace, sql-update

I have strings like this:

```
[text] STRING1[word] [text] STRING1[word] [text]
```

and I want to transform them into strings like this:

```
[text] STRING2[word]STRING3 [text] STRING2[word]STRING3 [text]
```

That is: I want to replace STRING1, keep the following word, and insert another string after this word.

Here's an example:

```
Monsieur &xp12334&x{Eccard travaille &xp12335&x{serieusement à mettre
```

I want to transform it into this string:

```
Monsieur <GND id="12334">Eccard</GND> travaille <GND id="12335">serieusement</GND> à mettre
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

I tried with INSTR and REPLACE but didn't get it right.

Comment: Do you need `select` or to update table?

Comment: I need to update it.

Comment: Can you provide example table before and after update. I'm not really sure how to do it with example you provided.

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: What database do you use and which version?

Comment: Access (.accdb)